# RabbitMQ memory management with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, memory-management, rabbitmq, node-amqp

I'm using the RabbitMQ management docker image. The issue is after around 1 week uptime, the disk space and the memory gets almost drained. I need to again terminate and restart it to function normally, but by doing so, all the existing messages in the queues are lost.

Command I use to start the rabbitmq server is : `docker run --rm -it --hostname my-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management`

> I'm using persistent messages and durable queues.

> No. of queues will be around 70.

> Connections per second may vary from 5 to 100

I'm using [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) npm module to interact with RabbitMQ using Nodejs.

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I configure on any server directly instead if using docker image? Is there any way to delete only the `acknowledged` messages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this is the definition of durability according to [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html) official documentation:

Durability

Queues can be durable or transient. Metadata of a durable queue is stored on disk, while metadata of a transient queue is stored in memory when possible. The same distinction is made for messages at publishing time in some protocols, e.g. AMQP 0-9-1 and MQTT.

**In environments and use cases where durability is important, applications must use durable queues and make sure that publish mark published messages as persisted.**

so if you are using durability in the messages section it means you are storing them to storage. rabbitmq comes with a functionality that you can ack your message. **if you ack the message it will be removed from the queue**.
so you have two options here for ack:

1. use auto ack mode **{ noAck: true }** :

   channel.consume(queue, function(msg) {
   // the message it self is here!
   }, {
   noAck: true
   });
2. ack manualiy:

   channel.consume(queue, function(msg) {
   // the message it self is here!
   // I can ack manually
   channel.ack(msg);
   }, {
   noAck: false
   });

so there is an article for optimization of rabbitmq:
https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2018-01-08-part2-rabbitmq-best-practice-for-high-performance.html